# Why does Software Updater window not appear when updates are available?

Tags: update-manager, 14.10, window

For a while now, whenever the Software Updater icon turns green to show that there are updates available, the window is invisible. It seems to happen only when Software Updater opens itself to show a new update is available. Clicking the the icon does nothing to make the window visible, I've tried alt-f7 to move it if it's hidden off screen but alt-f7 doesn't allow me to move anything. All I can do is right click on the icon and close it via that context menu and if I open Software Updater manually the window will then be visible. If I right click the icon when Software Updater is invisible, I can click an option to install updates but then the whole update process happens in the background and I don't get to see what I'm installing and I don't see any messages about restarting etc.,